# Building a tagger with spacy 3

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, pos-tagger, spacy-3

I want to add more words to the SpaCy model in portuguese so that I can use the PoS (part of speech) of a specific domain, but I don't want to add isolated words but sentences. I did these three steps:

1. I converted the "PetroTok-UDPIPE.conllu" file (freely available here: http://petroles.ica.ele.puc-rio.br/, this is inside of the "PetroTok" file and contains sentences (not individual words) with their respective PoS and lemmas) to a binary "PetroTok-UDPIPE.spacy" file, with the following command (indicated on the SpaCy page: https://spacy.io/usage/training#data):

[image]

```
python -m spacy convert PetroTok-UDPIPE.conllu .
```

This created the "PetroTok-UDPIPE.spacy" file.

2. Then, I created the "base_config.cfg" file (as indicated in the SpaCy page: https://spacy.io/usage/training#quickstart):

[image]

changing the values of "train" and "dev" to:

```
train = "PetroTok-UDPIPE.spacy"
dev = "PetroTok-UDPIPE.spacy"
```

(In this case I am considering the same data for train and validation, just for testing).

Having that file I use the following command line to create the "config.cfg" file (also indicated in the SpaCy page: https://spacy.io/usage/training#quickstart):

[image]

```
python -m spacy init fill-config base_config.cfg config.cfg
```

3. I apply the following command to create the model (as indicated in the SpaCy page: https://spacy.io/usage/training#quickstart):

[image]

```
python -m spacy train config.cfg --output ./output
```

That prints the following output:

[image]

...When testing a simple code loading the created model in the paste "output" it returns empty lists for the ".lemma_" and ".pos_" of the string "INTRODUÇÃO.":

```
lemma = ['', '']
pos = ['', '']
```

Could you please help me to identify the implicit error? I have another question, the model created in this way is created only with the "PetroTok-UDPIPE.conllu" file or is it a model that incorporates elements to the model in Portuguese (in this case)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your model is probably setting the `.tag_` attribute but not the `.pos_` attribute.

In the official models, what happens is that language-specific tags (`.tag_`) are learned by the model, and then an `AttributeRuler` maps them to Universal Dependency tags (`.pos_`). The quickstart doesn't configure that by default because there's different ways to do it, so you just get `.tag_`.

> I have another question, the model created in this way is created only with the "PetroTok.conllu" file or is it a model that incorporates elements to the model in Portuguese (in this case)?

The model will learn from scratch unless you tell it to do otherwise. Retraining a model without the other data is prone to catastrophic forgetting and not recommended, and training on two datasets for the same task with different tagsets sounds infeasible.

Comment: Yes, the model is returning the ".tag_" attribute, it would be great if it could also return the ".lemma_" attribute. Thanks.

Comment: If you want to have a model for the `UPOS`+`MORPH` columns (corresponding to `token.pos` and `token.morph`), add a `morphologizer` to the pipeline before training. From a UD corpus, you may not want `XPOS` at all (it depends on your task) and you can replace `tagger` with `morphologizer`.

Comment: Thank you! The "tagger" option in QuickStart allows returning the ".tag" attribute and the "morphologizer" option allows returning the ".pos_" attribute. None of the previous options allow you to return the lemmas (".lemma_", which are also contained in the *.conllu file), is there any way to do it?